# BusinessObjects - Changing Syntax in Generating Query

Tags: business-objects

When I make a query in BusinessObjects and when two tables are inner-joined, the BO generates the following script:

```
SELECT 
attr_1,... attr_N
FROM Table_1, Table_2
WHERE Table_1.key = Table_2.key
```

Is it possible to set BusinessObjets to generate queries in the following format:

```
SELECT
attr_1,..., attr_N
FROM Table_1
INNER JOIN
Table_2
ON Table_1.key = Table_2.key
```

When I want to check the query, it is much more easy to read the syntax in the second example.
Btw, I tried to modify some parameters. However, it didn't work. 
Any suggestion on how to do it quickly and easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on XI3...

In Designer, go to File -> Parameters.  Then click the Parameter tab.  In there you should see a parameter named "ANSI92"; change its value to Yes and click Replace.

[image]

**In BI4 IDT**, first open the universe's Data Foundation.  Then click on the .dfx file in the Data Foundation pane to select it:

[image]

This will bring up the Data Foundation settings in the lower right corner of the window.  Click the **Properties** tab, then the **Parameters** button:

[image]

In the dialog that comes up, you can change the ANSI92 option:

[image]

Comment: Hi Joe! I am using Information Design Tool 4.1. When I click on 'File' there is no 'Paramaeters' Option. Do you know how to do it with IDT?